# jmeter json extractor variable

Tags: json, jmeter

I am trying find a json value based on a variable (idSearch) which were set from a previous step.  I tried using the "json extractor" and set the following parms:

```
- Names of created variable: nameValue
- JSON Path expressions: $.[?(@.id_number == ${idSearch})].name
```

It doesn't seems to work.

json sample:

```
[{"id_number":12,"name":"John"},
 {"id_number":13,"name":"Ted"},
 {"id_number":14,"name":"Mary"}]
```

Desired result:
  -  if any of my json record matches my variable ($idSearch which equals to 12) then nameValue is set to 'John'
OR 
  - if any of my json record matches my variable ($idSearch which equals to 13) then nameValue is set to 'Ted'

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work fine, the only possible issue I can think of is that your `${idSearch}` variable is not defined or has the value which doesn't match your JSON input

Try looking into *jmeter.log* file and look for something like:

```
Error processing JSON content in JSON Extractor
```

If the line is present - you have a problem with the variable or JSON Extractor configuration.

You can also increase JMeter log verbosity for the JSON Extractor by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.extractor.json.jsonpath.JSONPostProcessor" level="debug" />
```

Once done you should see what exactly going on in *jmeter.log* file or in [Log Viewer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) window

[image: JMeter Log Viewer JSON Extractor]

Another potential problem is wrong JSON Extractor [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), you should place it **as a child** of the request which returns the above JSON, otherwise the `id` variable may be overwritten by subsequent samplers

You can check `${idSearch}` variable value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination:

[image]

Comment: I checked and my JSON extractor scope is set correctly.  Any other suggestion?